# Ajax doesnt work when Compilation Enabled

Tags: magento-1.7

I figured that Ajax add to cart doesnt work when Compilation is enabled. As well /admin page oftentimes is blank if I open it in a new browser.

The moment I DISABLE compilation, everything works perfectly.

*I tried running compilation and still, website doesnt function well when compilation is Enabled.

Any ideas why ?